# How to use a SELECT statement in WHERE LIKE for multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

I am trying to filter out rows from a table where the `[Description]` column includes words from a list in another table.

I have got this far and then realised I don't know how to do this at all:

```
SELECT 
  p.Description  --- a large amount of text
FROM
  Products p
WHERE 
  p.Description NOT LIKE 
(SELECT List.Word FROM List) --- pseudo code
```

So I need something similar to `NOT IN` but its actually `NOT LIKE` instead.

Is this possible without me having to manually extract all the words in the list and do a `NOT LIKE '%sofa%' AND NOT LIKE '%cushion%' AND NOT LIKE '%chair%'` etc etc?

Comment: How do you plan to separate words? Surely you don't want "%sofa%" to match "Insofar as the search was accurate."

Comment: That is going to be a problem. Ideally it should only match whole words and I'm not sure how to do that... maybe regex?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [full-text search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017). The performance is likely to be far better than using like with wildcards at both ends and it handles the word splitting issue.

Comment: @HABO I have implemented full-text search now and it works quite well. Only issue is that `CONTAINS()` doesn't accept an `nvarchar(MAX)` variable as a list of words to check. It will only accept `nvarchar(4000)` which is quite limiting if you have hundreds of words to check against.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could check if no row in `list` exists, where the `description` is like the `word` of that row.

```
SELECT p.description
       FROM products p
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM list l
                                WHERE p.description LIKE '%' + l.word + '%');
```

Comment: It probably doesn't scale very well as indexes are of little help with like queries like this. Maybe also check out full text indexing options for your database?

Comment: Works great for my initial needs. But eventually I'm going to have to do checks on whole word matching because of the problem HABO identified

Answer (score 2):

additionally to posted solution, you can use the following variant:

```
SELECT p.Description
FROM   Products p
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT Test = '%'+Word+'%' FROM List) AS c
                 ON p.Description LIKE c.Test
WHERE  c.Test IS NULL;
```

[**test is here**](http://rextester.com/FEE96367)